# Button long press to exit the app on Android PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have the following code:

```
function logout_now()

//Logout of the app after a long press onKey(Longer then 5 sec)    Not working correctly

{
var startTime; 
var endTime;
var TimeDiff;

document.getElementById('Exit_btn').addEventListener('touchstart',function(event)
        {startTime = new Date().getTime();
        },false);

document.getElementById('Exit_btn').addEventListener('touchend',function(event){
        endTime = new Date().getTime();
        TimeDiff = endTime-startTime;   

        if( endTime-startTime > 5000 )  //logout after more then 5 Second = 5000 mSec
            {
            logout();      
            }
        },true);     
 }
```

When the user presses the Exit_btn after waiting 5 seconds (long press) it starts the following function:

function logout()
{

```
var password = prompt("Please enter the exit password");

if (password == "123")
     {
        alert("Goodbye");
        navigator.app.exitApp();
     }
else
     {
        alert("Wrong Password!");
        console.log("index.html");
     }
```

}

The trouble is that it doesn't work smooth, meaning if I enter the wrong password the prompt box keep popping up, or if I finally exit the app properly, when I launch it again it crashes.

Can anyone see the problem here? Why does it happen?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery Mobile [**taphold**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) event, like below... this may help you...

Html:

```
<div id="logout-btn">Logout</div>
```

jQuery Mobile:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#logout-btn" ).on('taphold', tapholdCallBack);
     // Callback function
     function tapholdCallBack(ev) {
        logout();
        .....
     }
});
```

or

```
$(document).delegate('div[data-role*="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {
  $(document).delegate('#logout-btn', 'taphold', function (ev) {
    logout();
  });
});
```

Long press the logout button for 750 milliseconds, it will call logout().

By default tap duration is 750ms, if you want change the amount of time a tap should by assigning a value `to $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold`. like shown below...

```
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold = 5000,
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement this, but unfortunately the logout() function never called. I don't understand why..

Comment: @user1756004 : your logout() function only didn't get call or that taphold event callback function itself didn't get called..?

Comment: taphold event callback function did't get called. I set an alert there and it doesn't reacts.